# Kernel/user stack, what does it mean?

Tags: linux, uitableview, process, kernel, process-management

i'm preparing a small presentation about process management in linux kernel,
and while searching i found out that it's imperative for every process to have a task_struct or process 
descriptor and the second thing is a private kernel/user stack.
Now my question is **what's stack means?** is it memory space or what is exactly ? what is the kind of the object stack?

**any help will infinitely appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack is a memory space  that will have the saved variables, parameters of function and return addresses.